# Update and save value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following method checks if a coupon is valid or not. I would like to update the total amount in the current_cart when coupon is valid. The validation process works fine but for some reason it won’t update the amount in here cart/show.html.erb `<%= number_to_currency current_cart.amount %>`

coupons_controller.rb

```
def redeem
    @coupon = Coupon.find_by_discount_code(params[:discount_code])
 if @coupon.blank?
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Invalid!"
 else 
    @current_cart = Cart.find(current_cart.id)
    @current_cart.amount = @current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount
    @current_cart.save
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Valid!"
 end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
def current_cart 
  Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
  cart = Cart.create 
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  cart
end

  helper_method :current_cart
end

class Cart < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id) 
    if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
    else
    current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end


 def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
 end

 def tax_rate
   tax_amount = 0 
   line_items.each do |item|
   tax_amount += (item.product.price * item.quantity) *      item.product.tax_rate.rate
   end
   tax_amount
 end    

 def amount
   line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price } + tax_rate + fee
 end

 def fee
   shipment_amount = 0 
   line_items.each do |item|
    if item.quantity <= 1
    shipment_amount = item.product.shipment.fee
    else
    shipment_amount = item.product.multiple_shipment.fee
    end
  end
  shipment_amount
 end
end
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing `@` in front of `current_cart` when trying to save: `current_cart.save`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ Sebastian Muszyński! I tried this previously but whithout any result.

Comment: Fix it also in the previous line: `current_cart.amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here:

```
def amount
  line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price } + tax_rate + fee
end
```

`amount` is not a variable, but a method which adds together the prices of each item in the cart. You cannot change `amount`. The most straight-forward solution would be to add a new `discount` row to your Cart table:

```
class AddDiscountToCarts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :carts, :discount, :decimal, default: 0
  end
end
```

Then add it to your `amount` method:

```
def amount
  line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price } + tax_rate + fee - discount
end
```

And in your controller:

```
def redeem
  @coupon = Coupon.find_by_discount_code(params[:discount_code])
  if @coupon.blank?
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Invalid!"
  else 
    @current_cart = Cart.find(current_cart.id)
    @current_cart.discount = @coupon.amount
    @current_cart.save
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Valid!"
  end
end
```

**Be warned:** this code will still add full tax to your cart, even if the discount brings it down to 0. This is because your tax_rate method recalculates the amount using line items. You should never calculate your price multiple times because it'll introduce bugs and cost you extra work. Generally, tax rates are determined by location and applied to the total purchase after discounts. For some reason, you have itemized tax rates, which complicates things. But you could theoretically calculate a weighted average tax rate:

```
def tax_rate
  total_cost = line_items.inject(0) { |cost, item| cost += item.total_price } 
  weighted_rate = line_items.inject(0) do |rate, item|
    rate += (item.total_price * item.product.tax_rate.rate) / total_cost
  end
  return weighted_rate
end
```

And then use it in your `amount` function this way:

```
def amount
  (line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price } - discount + fee) * tax_rate
end
```

Comment: @Theopap glad to hear it! i also updated my answer with a suggestion on how to handle itemized tax rates.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem likely lies in these two lines:

```
@current_cart.amount = @current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount
@current_cart.save
```

Because you're not responding to the result of `#save` in any way, that can silently fail without giving any feedback to the user.

You have two options.

1) Cause it to raise an exception on fail:

```
@current_cart.save!
```

2) Add another layer of feedback if `#save` fails.

```
@current_cart.amount = @current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount

flash[:notice] =
  if @current_cart.save
    "Coupon is Valid!"
  else
    "Something went wrong."
  end

redirect_to :back
```

If you need to debug what's wrong further, a simple thing to do is log any errors from `#save` to the console:

```
if @current_cart.save
  "Coupon is Valid!"
else
  puts @current_cart.errors.to_json
  "Something went wrong."
end
```

Bonus tip: I'm trying to make sense of why you have a `current_cart` method and are doing the same work that it does to set a `@current_cart` instance variable. You should just be accessing that object via the `current_cart` method.

Because it's defined as a `helper_method`, you should be able to access that in the view without needing to set an instance variable as well.

If you cache the result of `current_cart` in an instance variable, then you can call it as many times as you want within the controller and view without any performance penalty:

```
def current_cart 
  @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
  @current_cart = Cart.create! # You probably want this to throw an exception if it fails
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  @current_cart
end

helper_method :current_cart
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your else clause to access the current_cart in a consistent manner.

```
else 
    @current_cart = Cart.find(current_cart.id)
    @current_cart.amount = @current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount
    @current_cart.save
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Valid!"
end
```

Comment: The original code has the @. I must have deleted it by mistake when copy and paste here. Thus, I already tried this previously but whithout any result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
@current_cart.amount = current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount
current_cart.save
```

Is missing the `@`.

Try with:

```
@current_cart.amount = @current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount
@current_cart.save
```

Comment: The original code has the @. I must have deleted it by mistake when copy and paste here. Thus, I already tried this previously but whithout any result.

Comment: `Cart.find(current_cart.id)` brings the correct value??

Comment: could you use `byebug`? just before the `.save`??